# Where is the documentation for Jenkins Workflow plugin?

Tags: jenkins-workflow

I found this:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workflow+Plugin

I want to use it but I can't find the documentation.

There's a README and a Tutorial page on GitHub. But the tutorial is not documentation - where do I find precise details of the commands available and syntax for each command in the Groovy-based DSL?

Answer (score 2):

I found some docs on cloudbees documentation page, for example:
[Chapter 29. Docker Workflow Plugin](https://documentation.cloudbees.com/docs/cje-user-guide/docker-workflow.html)

Although I think it's generally recommended to use the **Snippet Generator** for the syntax. You should see a checkbox in your job config.

```
http://<jenkins_host>:<port>/job/<job_name>/configure
```

Comment: Yes, for now all reference documentation is online, in _Snippet Generator_. In the future the same information may also be published in other formats.

Answer (score 0):

The Workflow plugin has been renamed to Pipeline.
Cloudbees, the company providing commercial support for Jenkins,
now provides full documentation for the Pipeline DSL at:

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/

Answer (score -1):

In the past few years, I have noticed that Jenkins Pipeline has become widely used, and more people are posting video tutorials for Pipeline:

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=jenkins+pipeline

I have looked at a few videos and have found them to be actually very good for helping new people quickly get introduced to writing Jenkins Pipeline scripts